# How Fit multiple Images (without loosing image clarity) in a row (in any view) in android

Tags: android

I am new to android. My requirement is as below. I have no code for this yet.

1. I want to put 5 images in a row and column using `GridLayout/GridView`.
2. I want to put this complete `GridLayout/GridView` in Vertical `ScrolView`.
3. This view should fill complete screen (irrespective of any screen size).

Example:

```
   <Relative Layout>
        <ScrolView>
        <GridView>
                  // All images in 5 rows and 5 columns
        <GridView>
        <ScrolView>
   </Relative Layout>
```

Please post the code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can implement a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager.

Here find a official documentation: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Its a very simple implementation, and its used in 99% of the actual ListData screen apps.

Answer (score 0):

Refer following link

http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android

[https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/05/make-a-gallery-like-image-grid-using-native-android/](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/05/make-a-gallery-like-image-grid-using-native-android/)

if your issue resolved, kindly upvote as well mark it correct

Comment: Please if you are referencing links, copy some of the relevant content here, as links can die.